# Generated Android key pair doesn't have certificate chain to attest

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am generating a key pair on Android device (8.1 / API level 27) using the following piece of code:

```java
KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        KEY_ALIAS,
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
    )
    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
    .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=X, O=X"))
    .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
    .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
    .build();

KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
generator.initialize(spec);

generator.generateKeyPair();
```

Then I want to attest that generated certificate is signed by the google root certificate to proof that certificate is stored in TEE (see [Verifying hardware-backed key pairs with Key Attestation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation)):

```java
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keystore
    .getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);


KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(
    privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey().getAlgorithm(),
    "AndroidKeyStore"
);
KeyInfo keyInfo = keyFactory.getKeySpec(privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey(), KeyInfo.class);

Log.i(TAG, "Is key in secure hardware: " + keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware());
Log.i(TAG, "Number of certificates in the chain: " + privateKeyEntry.getCertificateChain().length);
```

Which returns:

```
Is key in secure hardware: true
Number of certificates in the chain: 1
```

The only certificate in the chain is the certificate that contains generated public key. And it doesn't have [certificate extension data](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation#certificate_schema) to attest it.

How can I generate a key pair so that I have a certificate chain with extension data to attest?

Comment: The AndroidKeyStore generates by definition only [self-signed certificates](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#GeneratingANewPrivateKey). However it may be possible to import an existing certificate + key.

Comment: Hi @Robert , thanks, it makes sense now. Do you know how I can export existing certificate and public key from TEE?

Comment: The `AndroidKeyStore` is accessed using the `KeyStore` interface, therefore just use `KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");` and use it like any other keystore (except from the fact that you can't read private keys).

Comment: As far as I understood from your initial comment `AndroidKeyStore` keeps only self-signed certificates. How can I export android signed certificate that can be attested?

Comment: No it **generates** only self-signed. AFAIK it can keep any certificates you want if you import them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly request HW attestation by calling `setAttestationChallenge` on the `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder` instance, and passing it a server-side-generated nonce.

This will cause the Android Keystore to sign the public key cert using it's hardware protected key from the OEM (which is itself in turn signed by an intermediate CA key from Google, which is signed by a Google root CA key).

Then, get the full chain by calling `getCertificateChain` on the `KeyStore` instance.

Comment: https://github.com/vvb2060/KeyAttestation   sample project

Comment: thanks @DAC84.  please also refer to my reference implementation https://github.com/davidbarkhuizen/android-key-attestation-server